# Sublime Text 2 - Show Folders sidebar in different windows of same project

Tags: sublimetext2

How can I configure Sublime Text 2 to show the Folders sidebar in different windows of the same project?

To further clarify, I have a single window opened for a project:

[image: original window]

we see the `Folders` sidebar on the left, showing the hierarchy of the project (I've deleted a lot of content here due to privacy reasons). I proceed to drag the tab circled in red out to its own window.

Now, I get this window with the dragged out tab:

[image: new window]

When I use `View` -> `Side Bar` -> `Show Side Bar`, I get the `Open Files` sidebar, which shows the files opened in that window. But what I want is the `Folders` side bar, just like the original window.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Only drag and drop your folder to Side Bar of Sublime text

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate, I've attached a screenshot showing how to do it:

[image: solution]

I'm using Mac OS X, so I just opened up the `Finder` app, dragged the project folder over to the side bar and that shows the project folder hierarchy.